# A service that makes tcp connections to multiple clients

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcplistener, tcpserver

Most of the examples online are examples of a multithreaded tcp server, whereby the server listens for multiple incoming connections from the client.

What I'm looking for is for the "server", to initiate the connections. If I have 100 devices (all different IP address of course), my server will have to make 100 individual connections to each device and receive data from the devices.

This is how I would make my connection to a device

```
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);
_socket.SendTimeout = 2000;
_socket.ReceiveTimeout = 2000;
_socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress, TCPPort));
```

But I would like to know if there's any component out there, that would fulfill the following

- establish as many tcp connections as I want to the devices
- receive & send data through the connection
- handle tcp timeouts/disconnects/etc & re-establish connection to the IP

If there aren't any of such components, are there any tips as to how I should go about doing it? e.g., 1 connection per thread, or how do I handle if the data is received in multiple packets, etc?

Any insights would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several existing components out there that you could use to achieve what you want. Checkout http://www.networkcomms.net and http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/.

Having said that people always prefer to add that there is nothing stopping you writing everything from scratch yourself as per the example you give.

Disclaimer: I'm a developer for NetworkComms.Net.

Comment: I agree with @MarcF.  I'm a graduate research student (in AI) myself and many times, it can be quite useful to write what you need from scratch as it circumvents the need for understanding an API (which can be sparse or complex in some cases) and provides the precise functionality you need, all at the cost of the time it takes to write it yourself.